# Initializing a struct outside of main() using malloc (C89)

Tags: c, linked-list, malloc

I'm trying to implement a doubly linked list in C and I need to use an initialize function, while maintaining a size field. My code is as follows:

```
typedef struct element{
    struct element* next;
    struct element* prev;
    int value;
}element_t;

typedef struct linkedlist{
    element_t* head;
    element_t* tail;
    int size;
}linkedlist;

void init(linkedlist* list){
    list = malloc(sizeof(linkedlist));
    list->size = 0;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    linkedlist* list;
    init(list);
    return 0;
```

When I'm trying to access list->size in the init function, I get the correct value, But when I try to access list->size from main the program returns a strange, large negative value (probably an address in hex).

Would like to know what I'm doing wrong. stdlib is included.

Comment: I don't get the down votes. It is a clear question with the code provided.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are only modifying a local copy of `list` which `main` will never see. You probably want to do something like this:

```
linkedlist* init(void) { // <<<
    linkedlist* list = malloc(sizeof(linkedlist)); // <<<
    list->size = 0;
    return list; // <<<
}

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    linkedlist* list = init(); // <<<
    return 0;
}
```

---

If you have to keep the original function signature, then you must not modify `list` within `init`. You could do something like this instead:

```
void init(linkedlist* /* const */ list){
    list->size = 0;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    linkedlist list; //<<<
    init(&list); //<<<
    return 0;
```

Comment: This works, but how should I implement the function signature:
    void init(linkedlist* list)
which I'm limited to?

Comment: You can't - you either use the above method, or you use @dbush's method, or you do the `malloc` (or equivalent) outside `init` (e.g. in `main`), so that the `list` pointer is not modified.

Comment: Very well, I'll keep on that - thanks

Comment: Another issue that annoys me - how come I can modify values of the structure (as done on the init function) while it is not yet allocated anywhere in the memory?

Comment: @Triumphan: C is a low level language which provides you with an infinite number of different ways to shoot yourself in the foot. Just because something *appears* to work you should never assume that it is correct to do so.

Comment: @Triumphan Eh? `init` allocates `list` and then modifies it.

Answer (score 2):

In C, all parameters are pass by value.  So the `list` variable in `init` is a **copy** of the value of `list` in `main`, and it is that copy that is being modified.  So the change isn't seen outside of the function.

You need to pass the **address** of `list` into `init`, and change that function to accept a pointer-to-pointer.

```
void init(linkedlist **list){
    *list = malloc(sizeof(linkedlist));
    (*list)->size = 0;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    linkedlist *list;
    init(&list);
    return 0;
}
```